# Cryptic clue: Are you bowled over by this beauty?

Tags: knowledge, rebus, crossword-clues

Can you solve the following cryptic clue?

...... (6)

Hint 1:

> Think Rebus.

Hint 2:

> Look at the number of dots. Think of a sport.

Hint 3:

> Edited title to lead you closer ;)

Comment: Where's Bailey M when you need him?

Comment: @JLee Maybe he's down the Mold Bailey?

Comment: Unfortunately, my forte is with words, not dots!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> MAIDEN

as in

> A maiden over in cricket, or 6 (dot) balls without a run being scored, as it would be displayed on a score sheet

Comment: Thank you! You saved me the ignominy of having to answer my own question :)

Comment: @Bravo if this is the right answer, could you please accept it?

Comment: how are people supposed to solve rebus involving cricket?

Comment: @njzk2 If they know something about cricket I suppose

Comment: @Pete: I know they killed a grillion people in the war.  Does that help?

Comment: As someone who's never watched cricket, I feel offended. #millennial

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Tulips 
> "Two ellipsis" sounds like tulips. Tulips are considered by many to be beautiful [citation needed], and also has six characters.

Comment: "sounds like" needs an indicator for crossword clues. Please look at hint 2.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> Cerium.  The six periods refers to a [Period 6 element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_6_element).  There are four Period 6 elements that are six letters long: barium, cerium, osmium, and erbium.  Cerium's name comes from Ceres, the Roman goddess of agriculture, and presumably all Roman goddesses were beauties.

Comment: You make an important observation which others have overlooked. However the answer is wrong, since there are many elements and the association to beauty is, as you agree yourself, is tenuous :) Please look at hint 2.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is

> POINTS,

but

> DOTTED and BLANKS

also fit the clue perfectly well. IMO the question is too broad.

Comment: The answer is specific and more convincing than that. Also pl. note the change in title :)

Comment: how do either of those fit the 6 in parens?

Comment: @JLee They're 6 letters long! That's what (6) always means in crosswords.

Comment: but, it's a rebus, right?

Comment: @Bravo I came up with an even better one, but not sure how it fits with beauty...

Comment: Please look at hint 2.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> [The Six Point Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Point_Group)
>  It was a British feminist campaign founded in 1921. The beauty in title could point to the fact that it was a women's movement.

Comment: No, I'm sure "(6)" means the answer is 6 letters long. Otherwise it'd be *extremely* confusing as a crossword clue!

Comment: Hmm, I agree. I just got carried away by the rebus tag. :-P

Comment: Yes randal is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> STRIKE

Someone that is beautiful is said to be

> striking

Also, you could

> bowl a strike.

If you look at the dots, they look a little like

> the bottoms of the 5 pins as they're knocked down at the end of a bowling lane + 1 ball.